# Initializing class properties in TypeScript using ES6 class getters / setters

Tags: typescript

I am trying to initialize a variable within a class constructor. However, I wish to check the value and enforce some constraints on it so I have used ES6 class getters/setters.

The problem I am having is that I am calling the setter from within the constructor but TypeScript complains stating:

*(property) Meter._status: string
Property '_status' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.*

I am aware that I can initialize _status directly within the constructor. However, as mentioned I need to check the value and enforce additional constraints.

Is this not possible within TypeScript? and if it is, how do I do that given the example below.

```
class Meter {

    private _status: string;

    constructor(status: string) {
      this.status = status;
    } 

    set status(status:string) {
      if(status === 'on' || status === 'off') {
        this._status = status
      } else {
          console.log('Invalid status provided');
      }
    }

    get status() {
      return this._status
    }

}

export default Meter;
```

I am aware that I could also initialize the property with an empty string first and then set the value as below. However, it feels a bit hacky and would add a lot of additional code when adding more properties.

```
class Meter {

    private _status: string;

    constructor(status: string) {
      // initialize _status with an empty string
      this._status = '';

      // set the actual value of status
      this.status = status;
    } 

    set status(status:string) {
      if(status === 'on' || status === 'off') {
        this._status = status
      } else {
          console.log('Invalid status provided');
      }
      
    }
    get status() {
      return this._status
    }

}

export default Meter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Definite Assignment Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions). It tells TypeScript that a variable is indeed assigned for all intents and purposes, even if TypeScript’s analyses cannot detect so.

```js
class Meter {
    private _status!: string;
    //            ^^^ definite assignment assertion

    constructor(status: string) {
      this.status = status;
    } 

    set status(status:string) {
      if(status === 'on' || status === 'off') {
        this._status = status
      } else {
          console.log('Invalid status provided');
      }
    }

    get status() {
      return this._status
    }
}

export default Meter;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=22&pc=22#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCmAXeAnaBvAUNH0AOKAlgG5jLQD6EiZArhAIQBc01RAdgOYDc2uA9P1zCRAPXHQAJvABmhdoXKQIhTuwC28domjLUiQgHt2mPjmDG2tYIkMoAFNToQWbeZwCUGM7kQALQggAOidEemgAXlYaMIheYQBfaFNhCCRo50cY+iY3Li8sEWhCGSznSIiogHJjKugAH3qM2IrqwxkZKoKfYX9AoKpsmCjQ+h7oJPgQNO8i4Qt2CEMQeCCQQ057KoBJdlIQQklm8IJDYkP4SS74kQSfO59OdNGIe26ilCRaFHZoPuDBs57pgHvAAB54Ow6aQyMC0EA6BDIFDcIA)

Answer (score 0):

It is actually simple. You only need to add a property initializer like this:

```
class Meter {

    private _status: string = '';

    constructor(status: string) {
      // set the actual value of status
      this.status = status;
    } 

    set status(status:string) {
      if(status === 'on' || status === 'off') {
        this._status = status
      } else {
          console.log('Invalid status provided');
      }
      
    }
    get status() {
      return this._status
    }

}

export default Meter;
```

---

EDIT: As Shivam Singla mentioned you can also use the define assignment assertion like this:

```
class Meter {

    private _status!: string;

    constructor(status: string) {
      // set the actual value of status
      this.status = status;
    } 

    set status(status:string) {
      if(status === 'on' || status === 'off') {
        this._status = status
      } else {
          console.log('Invalid status provided');
      }

    }
    get status() {
      return this._status
    }

}

export default Meter;
```

It tells the TypeScript compiler to pretend that the value will be initialized there. If you want to try it, the code is here:

- [Example 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCmAXeAnaBvAUJ6voAcUBLANzGWgH0JFyBXCALmhuIDsBzaAXmgHI+Abmx5owAPZtWdYInEoAFDXpMWidhwCUGHKOgB6fSyTREAC3jQwsumBDQyIOpfEAzNSt2jzRCADplRAYeDyCIYVEAX2gRPAgTQIYlWjDGViJObSw9aCJXZJUebl4+ST5oAB8K0ODikrdXPiyvPR9-ahTamogW3Gj4EHidHNEJKXEQeD8QcQ4FPgBJNkciABNughRxEjX4VaaIvUjemKiWjgTOiAVmnJQkOhQ2UzNfPw7PM8xjzHgAD3w8kQ0FW8FcYDoIGBCGQKEEQA)
- [Example 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCmAXeAnaBvAUJ6voAcUBLANzGWgH0JFyBXCAQgC5obiA7AcwG5s9owAPYd2dYIiEoAFDXoRW7ItwCUGHAOgB6LWyTREAC3jQwEumBDQyIOiaEAzNrUQMNAo0QgA6Oa5gAvM7yfAIAvtD8eBD6fgyyLgzMSqrqmtBEDgny0AF50ADkIgXQAD6lwf65+UUODgVqWOm4nj7UiYGVbukR8CAxac24wqJCIPDeIEJc0gUAkhw2RAAmXTCEQiQr8MsNoZphUbiHAlyxHdKN7ngoSHQoHAaGXt7t8teHmJ-wAB74UohoMt4A4wHQQICEMgUDwgA)

Comment: Great thanks. I wasn't sure if it was best practice to initialize the property within the constructor or I could just do it as in your example.

Comment: I guess my only concern with doing it that way is if the property type is something a bit more complex than a string. For example a typed object. That then could require quite a bit of additional code just to initialize a number of properties in that way.